# Determine if a unit is available in the next three months for at least 3 months

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, where-clause

I can determine if a unit is available today easy enough my looking at all the tenants Move in and move out dates.

In Mysql SQL it looks like this

Occupied today - Example if today is 2020-09-01

```
SELECT Tenant.Unit
FROM Tenants
WHERE ((tenant.MoveInDate is not null and tenant.MoveInDate <= '2020-09-01') 
     AND (tenant.MoveOutDate >= '2020-09-01' OR tenant.MoveOutDate is NULL))
```

But how using this same information can i determine if a unit is available in the next three months for at least three months or not available.

If tenant has a move-in date but null move-out date it is because they are still in the unit therefore the unit they have is occupied today. If a tenant has a null move in then they have, of course,  a null move out. So they haven't moved in yet. If they have a move in date in the future it is still available today. But they will be a future tenant. I hope this provides some context.

But it is more complicated than this because this is about units more than the tenant so I need to make sure the unit is available for at least three months. In other words, are there any tenants moving into this unit less than three months after a tenant moves in because then we don't want to consider this unit  available.

Unit can be occupied by multiple tenants so we have to consider all tenants in a unit when determining the rule.

[image]

Comment: first of all, if you don't know `MoveOutDate` for a tenant, you can't. If you have option to set `MoveOutDate` to a future date and that date is there, then definitely you can.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Comment: Not enough information to solve this.  You would need to provide the move out date.

Answer (score 0):

Your original query, that checks which units are available today, probably does not do exactly what you want. I think the logic you want is:

```
select unit
from tenants
where moveindate is null           -- not noved in yet
    or moveindate  > '2019-09-01'  -- will move in later on
    or moveoutdate < '2019-09-01'  -- moved out before today
```

Now, changing the query to check for the next three months is straight forward:

```
select unit
from tenants
where moveindate is null           -- not noved in yet
    or moveindate >= '2012-12-01'  -- will movin later than 3 months in the future
    or moveoutdate < '2019-09-01'  -- moved out before today
```

Comment: @user3092412: I think I understand. I edited my answer. You should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27188591) to add this important piece of information.